# Why doesn't SQLException extends IOException?

Tags: java, exception, jdbc

As a client, when something "bad" happens with input / output of my program, an I/O exception should be thrown. Now when I'm connected to a server, my program has an input-output-relationship as the client to the said server. Therefore, when something on the communication doesn't work (something "bad"), the resulting exception should be an IOException, i.e. SQLException should extend IOException.

Why is this not the case?

Comment: What makes you think that any SQL related problem has to do with IO problems?

Comment: Why should a "syntax error" be an IOException?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because a `SQLException` is not always related to IO.

For example if you write a bad SQL command you will have a `SQLException`.

Here is a non exhaustive list of possible SQLExceptions not related to IO:

- Bad sql grammar
- Wrong attribute numbers
- Wrong attribute types
- Constraint violation
- Privilege problems
- Duplicate primary keys
- Not existing table or column names

From [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html):

> An exception that provides information on a database access error **or other errors**.

Comment: So to be the most accurate we would need multiple inheritance to indicate if an exception is both an SQL exception and an I/O exception, but we can't have that with Java, right?

Comment: Is the driver that hides what happens in the communication between client (java app) and server. Probably an IOException is thrown at a lower level, but it is intercepted and changed to a SQLException.

Answer (score 1):

Because the SQLException is not necessarily an IOException. It may be wrong syntax, format, ... IOException is intended to be returned by the I/O devices (originally stream, such as file and network operations), not necessarily any input/output from your program.

Comment: "such as file and network operations" isn't server access a network operation?

Comment: Not necessarily. You may have embedded databases, syntax errors, etc. In this case it's nothing wrong with the IO itself. The IOException is really meant to handle device/environment rather than application exceptions. The driver may throw an IOException if the network is broken though

Answer (score 0):

An SQL-Exception must not be necessarily a IO-Exception (such as Connection loss, Read Timeout, etc.).

A bad SQL or a constraint violation can also raise an SQL-Exception.

Answer (score 0):

You could try catching both, say

```
try
{..  some code..}
Catch (IOException ex)
{... handle IOException (say - wait a minute and try again 10 times)...}
Catch (SqlClientException ex)
{... handle SQL errors Exception (log in a custom table) ...}
Catch (Exception ex)
{... log all other Exception ...}
```